# 3D Coordinates after rotating

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, three.js

I have 2 points: C and P

I want to rotate P around C in 3 dimensions.

How can i calculate the new position of P?

I have two angle: 'yaw' and 'pitch'.

Yaw moves P around C on the 'x' axis, so it moves it left+ and right- around the point.

Pitch moves P around C on the 'y' axis, so it moves it up+ and down- around the point.

Z, depth moves toward you in +, moves away from you in -

Of course i want to make it work with 'intermediate' positions too, like 45deg yaw and 45deg pitch.

Yaw and Pitch is given in DEG, then converted to RAD (before this code, so the code uses RAD)

```
p.x = c.x + Math.sin(yaw) * Math.sin(pitch);
p.y = c.y + Math.cos(yaw);
p.z = c.z + Math.cos(yaw) * Math.cos(pitch);
```

Imagine a Sphere and a Point, i want to move the Point on the Sphere's surface.

This sometimes work, sometimes not. What am i missing?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, i have no idea what should i search for.

Here is a fiddle about my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Jm6Lt/2/

Blue sphere's position is calculated, white sphere is rotated around the red sphere's center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote down are the spherical coordinates on a sphere of radius 1 around C.

Look up "rotation matrix" and "Givens rotation", these are the kind of operations that  will rotate a given point. The type of operation that you are looking for will have the form

```
P'=C+R*(P-C),
```

where R is a rotation matrix.

---

You got the spherical coordinates slightly wrong, they should be:

```
p.x = c.x + Math.sin(yaw) * Math.sin(pitch);
p.y = c.y + Math.cos(yaw);
p.z = c.z + Math.sin(yaw) * Math.cos(pitch);
```

Then the vector for `(yaw, pitch)=(0,0)` is `(0,1,0)` (before translation by C) and the coordinates describe its rotation, first in the y-z-plane around the x axis with angle yaw and after that around the y axis with angle pitch.

Comment: I see, but why my code gives wrong result? Sometimes the values are just '0'. I have no rotation matrix, only the coordinates and the angles.

Comment: There was a cos in the z-component where there should be a sin.

Comment: I can't understand what is going on, i have made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jm6Lt/2/ Here you can see 3 spheres and a cylinder. Red sphere is the C, blue P, white P2. P's position is the calculated point (used your answer), P2 is a rotated sphere, it is rotated around C. The cylinder is the same as P2, but it is a cylinder. Why P gives wrong result? Or what is going on? Did i misunderstand something? Thanks.

Comment: With rotations it is extremely important in which order they are applied. One would have to look into the documentation to see what the effect of setting the rotation.x and .z variables is, in which order they are applied to get from the local to the global coordinate system.